# Python character search in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a txt which first line include the good answers of a test, and the other lines include the ID of the participants and they answers (' ' between). If the user give an input (call it n) its means the number of the question, and I have to count how many of them are good (similar which is in the [0] line n's) 
The txt's like:

BCCCDBBBBCDAAA

AB123 BXCDBBACACADBC

AD995 BABCDABCBCBBBA

AH97 BCACDBDDBCBBCA

AK260 DCDCBDDAACDBDB

AL580 AACCDBBCDCAACA

AN562 BAABBDCACCBDBB

And my code is:

```
person=[]
with open('answers.txt', 'r') as v: 
    pcs=sum(1 for line in open('answers.txt'))
    for i in range(0, pcs):
        person.extend(v.read().strip().split())
result=0
jnum=input('which exesises result are you interested in? ')
jnum=int(jnum)
good=person[0]
good=good[jnum]
for i in range(0, pcs):
    letter=person[i*2]
    letter=letter[jnum]
    if good==letter:
        result+=1 
        print(result)
    else:
        result=result
```

Comment: That is *not* a list...

Comment: Your single example of input and result is not enough to specify the problem you're trying to solve.  Please be *clear* about your definition of "similar" for this program.  Also, provide a *complete* example; the posted code hangs, waiting for input, and `list` (which is a bad variable name, being a built-in data type) is not defined.

Comment: Okay I'll write it out

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will freeze, once you fix enough problems to get that far: your final two lines are an infinite loop.  You don't change either `good` or `letter` within the loop -- as soon as they match, you're stuck inside.

Insert `print` statements to trace your execution and data values.

Also, I strongly recommend that you adopt incremental programming.  Your code has multiple problems; you should write just a few lines, make *sure* that they work, and then go on to the next small group.